# Wireless Dropping Out Using Intel 7260AC Card (Deauthenticated - Reason 7)

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, kernel, intel

I have recently bought a new laptop and it has an Intel 7260AC wireless card in it. I am getting regular wireless dropouts occurring at no specific interval. AFAIK this only occurs at my house.

Things I have tried

- Update to the newest mainline kernel (3.15)
- Update to the new drivers on the intel website (copied the iwlwifi-7260-8.ucode into /lib/firmware and rebooted).
- Turned off power management
- Switched home wireless to WEP

I'm at a loss for things to do. This is absolutely crippling at home.

Here's some outputs of various logs

**dmesg**

```
[ 8537.229038] wlan0: associated
[ 8717.623176] wlan0: deauthenticated from 00:14:bf:eb:1e:8a (Reason:7=CLASS3_FRAME_FROM_NONASSOC_STA)
[ 8717.640886] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 8717.644652] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 8717.644657] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[ 8717.644659] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain,     max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[ 8717.644661] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 8717.644663] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 8717.644664] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 8717.644665] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 8717.644667] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 8717.683218] wlan0: authenticate with 00:14:bf:eb:1e:8a
[ 8717.689440] wlan0: send auth to 00:14:bf:eb:1e:8a (try 1/3)
[ 8717.691624] wlan0: authenticated
[ 8717.692710] wlan0: associate with 00:14:bf:eb:1e:8a (try 1/3)
[ 8717.696209] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:14:bf:eb:1e:8a (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=6)
[ 8717.699638] wlan0: associated
[ 8840.203683] wlan0: deauthenticated from 00:14:bf:eb:1e:8a (Reason: 7=CLASS3_FRAME_FROM_NONASSOC_STA)
[ 8840.228674] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 8840.230683] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 8840.230685] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[ 8840.230687] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[ 8840.230689] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 8840.230690] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 8840.230691] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 8840.230693] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 8840.230694] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm),  (N/A)
```

**lshw -C network**

```
  *-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Ethernet Connection I218-V
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 19
   bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 04
   serial: 28:d2:44:80:9a:25
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.3.2-k firmware=0.6-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:64 memory:f0600000-f061ffff memory:f063e000-f063efff ioport:3080(size=32)
  *-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 7260
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 83
   serial: 7c:7a:91:f2:1e:30
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.15.0-031500-generic firmware=22.15.8.0 ip=10.10.10.107 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
   resources: irq:62 memory:f0400000-f0401fff
```

**uname -a**

```
 3.15.0-031500-generic #201406081435 SMP Sun Jun 8 18:36:00 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**iw reg get**

```
country 00:
(2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
(2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
(2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
(5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
(5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
```

**ls /lib/firmware | grep iwlwifi**

```
iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-7.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-8.ucode
iwlwifi-3945-2.ucode
iwlwifi-4965-2.ucode
iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
iwlwifi-7260-8.ucode
```

Is it possible "iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode" is conflicting with "iwlwifi-7260-8.ucode"? Should I remove it? What else could be wrong? I just cant believe that its my router if my brand new laptop is the only device in the house affected by this.

Comment: I have the exact same problem and have been looking for a solution for months. It's killing me when I work from home.

Comment: I think that `wlan0: deauthenticated from 00:14:bf:eb:1e:8a (Reason: 7=CLASS3_FRAME_FROM_NONASSOC_STA)` is the important part of `dmesg`. Have you checked the rest of the logs? `sudo egrep 'wlan0|cfg80211' /var/log/*`

Comment: I just googled "CLASS3_FRAME_FROM_NONASSOC_STA" and got many results. I'll leave the reading to you @dty and user290670